# Customising ViewComponent View location

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

So I followed the MSDN guide on ViewComponents and it gives me this nugget on customising where a `ViewComponent` will look for its view:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddRazorOptions(options =>
    {
        options.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/{0}.cshtml");
    })
.SetCompatibilityVersion(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
```

Where `{0}` becomes `Components/{View Component Name}/{View Name}`

That means in the ViewComponent I'd direct it by using:

```
public class CreateVC : ViewComponent
{
    public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
    {
        return View("Hello");
    }
}
```

and it'd look for `Components/CreateVC/Hello.cshtml`

I want to get rid of `Components` part. Actually I'd like to get rid of the `CreateVC` part in that default string too, so I can put `options.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/Views/{0}.cshtml");` in the `startup`, call it with `return view(nameof(namespacefolder) + "Hello")` and then it'd look in `Views/namespacefolder/Hello.cshtml`

**How can I change `{0}` to not be `Components/{View Component Name}/{View Name}`** ?? and instead just be `/{View Name}` ??

Answer (score 0):

Turns out LocationExpanders should be able to do this but

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/10277

Shows there's a bug that MicroSoft are ignoring that means we CANNOT override this string for `ViewComponents` - I will have to come up with some roundabout way to specify my exact locations without using magic strings.